# Tweet Me at TAM13

Tags: discussion, conference

I am currently attending [The Amaz!ng Meeting](https://www.amazingmeeting.com/). I will be live tweeting the event as it goes along, so feel free to follow me [@LarianLeQuella](https://twitter.com/LarianLeQuella).  Also, if you look over [the schedule of events](https://www.amazingmeeting.com/the-amazng-meeting-2015/schedule/), and see a speaker or topic you would like to ask a question of, send me a direct tweet, and I will ask it on behalf of you and Skeptic Stack Exchange.  Remember, it must be less than 149 characters, and must end with a question mark.

Also, this year, apparently the hashtag getting used is #TAM13, although I would also occasionally check #TAM2015.  Things may change since the conference hasn't officially started yet.